# Automatically inject methods to a class on compile-time

Tags: c#, postsharp

Basically, what I want is:

If I have a class definition like this:

```
public class MyClass()
{
    public int MyMethod()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

I want to inject a different copy of all the methods on compile-time.

So the actual compiled version would (for instance) look like this:

```
public class MyClass()
{
    public int MyMethod()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    // injected method ...
    public int MyMethodInjected()
    {
        return MyMethod() * 2; // just an example
    }
}
```

I know this should be possible using PostSharp using a type attribute, but can't figure out how to do it. All aspect attributes I have looked at simply modify the existing method, which is not what I want. I want to create a new injected method for each method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible with PostSharp Aspect Framework as you cannot name the introduced method. For reference, consider the following:

```
[DuplicateAspect]
public class TargetClass
{
    public int MyMethod()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

// We want the aspect to apply to types and provide other aspects.
[PSerializable]
public class DuplicateAspect : TypeLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        Type targetType = (Type)targetElement;

        foreach (MethodInfo method in targetType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        {
            // For each public instance method declared in the target type, apply an aspect that duplicates a single method.
            yield return new AspectInstance(targetType, new DuplicateSingle(method));
        }
    }
}

// We want the aspect to be instance-scoped and provide advices.
[PSerializable]
public class DuplicateSingle : IAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect, IAdviceProvider
{
    private MethodInfo sourceMethod;
    public Func<int> Method;

    public DuplicateSingle(MethodInfo sourceMethod)
    {
        this.sourceMethod = sourceMethod;
    }

    public IEnumerable<AdviceInstance> ProvideAdvices(object targetElement)
    {
        Type targetType = (Type)targetElement;
        FieldInfo field = typeof(DuplicateSingle).GetField(nameof(Method));
        MethodInfo method = typeof(DuplicateSingle).GetMethod(nameof(IntroducedMethod));

        // Provide import method advices, which stores delegate into a field of the aspect upon instance creation (remember - instance scoped aspect).
        yield return new ImportMethodAdviceInstance(field, this.sourceMethod.Name, false, ImportMemberOrder.BeforeIntroductions);

        // Provide introduce method advice, which introduces a stub calling the aspect method into the target class.
        // PROBLEM: It's not possible to rename the method, hence this will fail.
        yield return new IntroduceMethodAdviceInstance(method, PostSharp.Reflection.Visibility.Public, false, MemberOverrideAction.Fail);
    }       

    public object CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
    {
        return new DuplicateSingle(this.sourceMethod);
    }

    public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
    }

    public int IntroducedMethod()
    {
        return this.Method() * 2;
    }
}
```

The introduced method will be always named same as method info you provide to the advice instance (there is currently no way to change the introduce method name).

Since there is not larger benefit of introducing methods dynamically, I do not think that this would ever be implemented as a valid use case of PostSharp.

I would suggest more low level IL-rewriting tools such as Mono CeCil.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Daniel.

Comment: @Daniel Balas, can you please explain a bit more what your _reference code_ does?

Comment: @AntonKrouglov Added comments leading to the problem I describe. Is it ok?

Comment: @Daniel Balas - thank you. Given the names as fixed (say `IntroducedMethod1`) is it possible with PostSharp to add dynamic attributes like `[XmlAttribute("MyMethod")]` to `IntroducedMethod1`?

Comment: @AntonKrouglov Take a look at http://doc.postsharp.net/t_postsharp_aspects_advices_copycustomattributesattribute